# SVG with flowroots conversion in Ruby

Tags: ruby, svg, imagemagick, png, inkscape

I'm trying to convert a SVG to PNG which has a flowroot element in it. Inkscape does it fine, when I convert using Cairo or imagemagick the flowroot elements appear as an opaque box rather than rendering the text within it.

I'm thinking this is because flowroots are a part of SVG 1.2. Does anyone know of any other gems/libraries that might help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just export it to PNG from inkscape then?

You'll find that flowRoot isn't supported anywhere except inkscape. It's defined in an old working draft of SVG 1.2 Full, and if you look at the last published [SVG 1.2 Full working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG12/) you'll find this:

> Notable changes to the feature set that readers can expect to see in
>   the next draft include:
>
> - Replacement of the previous flowing text proposal with a superset of    the SVG 1.2 Tiny textArea feature.

That said, the SVG WG is working on [SVG2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/) instead, so you should probably look there if you want to know where things are headed.

Comment: Thanks Erik, Yes we ended up using inkscape system call to export the PNG. Is there any other way around flowroots that is supported by the likes of Cairo and ImageMagick? Basically we need a text within a block.

Comment: Instead of flowRoot use `text` and `tspan` elements, that will be the most compatible. You can also use `textPath` to make the text follow along some predefined lines, but I'm not sure how well `textPath` is supported in ImageMagick.

Comment: I think we are able to get it working using text-anchor, basically we want text aligned and we might somehow get around clipping as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install libRSVG?

This [post](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=10275&p=33920#p32309) says:

> textPath is not implemented in the built-in SVG converter of IM. However if available IM will use the libRSVG library to do SVG conversion, and this does get it right.

Comment: Unfortunately libRSVG is apparently the underlying problem here. It can't render flowroot properly. That discussion is about textpaths.